# execCommand in internet explorer saves the csv file using USC-2 Little endian encoding, how to save it with UTF-8 format?

Tags: javascript, html, csv, utf-8, character-encoding

The execCommand always save the .csv file in USC-2 little indian format, but I want it in UTF-8 format. Also when I change the file name to .txt, the encoding is properly UTF-8. How can I achevie UTF-8 encoding for csv file? I did try to set charset to UTF-8 but it did not work.

```
var oWin = window.open("about:blank", "_blank");
oWin.document.open("application/csv", "replace");
oWin.document.charset = "utf-8";
oWin.document.write(csvText);
oWin.document.close();
var success = oWin.document.execCommand('SaveAs', true, 'fileName.csv');
oWin.close();
alert(success);
```

**The file is generated with proper contents but the encoding is not UTF-8 and hence excel does not recognize columns and entire row is displayed in single column.**
Produced file (fileNam.csv):

```
"Column One","Column Two","Column Three"
"row1 Col1","row1 Col2"
"row2 Col1","row2 Col2","row2 Col3"
"row3 Col1","row3 Col2","row3 Col3"
```

**I want to do this using javascript and specifically for IE. I know that for other browsers the HTML5 download tag can be used.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what was missing, we need to explicitly say what is the separator. The below line should be added before writing to document

```
csvText = 'sep=,\r\n' + csvText;
```

[AndrewB - Convert HTML table to CSV in jQuery](http://andrew-b.com/view/article/44)
, is the column separator and \r\n is row separator. Also, if you are writing this using c/c++, we need to escape \r\n as \r\n and depending on context use ' or "